# Difference between template name and template id

Tags: c++, templates

C++ Standard

> Section 14/2 :
>
> In a function template declaration, 
>   the *declarator-id* shall be a
>   *template-name* (i.e., not a
>   *template-id*).  [*Note:* in a class
>   template declaration, if the
>   *declarator-id* is  a  *template-id*, the 
>   declaration  declares  a  class 
>   template  partial specialization.

What is the difference between a `template-name`, `template-id` and a `type-id`?

Does the above quote mean we cannot write something like

```
template <>
void templatefunction<int>(){ // ...}
```

or have I misunderstood the point?

Answer (score 32):

The *template-name* is the name of the template.  In your example, `templatefunction` is a *template-name*.

The *template-id* is the name of the template with the template arguments list.  In your example, `templatefunction<int>` is the *template-id*.  A *template-id* names a template specialization.

A *type-id* names a type.  A *template-id* is a *type-id*; a *template-name* is not (because it does not name a type; it names a template).

The text you cite from 14/2 concerns a *template-declaration*, which declares a primary template.  Your example is not a *template-declaration*, it is an *explicit-specialization* (14.7.3/1).

Answer (score 8):

A declarator-id is the syntactical element that specifies the name in a simple-declaration ("type name;"). In the following "A" and "B::C" is the declarator-id

```
int A;
int B::C;
int A();
int *A;
int A[42];
template<typename T> void A();
```

---

A type-id syntactically is roughly a simple-declaration where the declarator-id is missing. A type-id is used as the syntactical element in a template type argument and in a cast.

```
int // type-id
int* // type-id
int[] // type-id
int() // type-id
int(*)() // type-id
```

---

A template-name is the name of a template. Syntactically it appears before a template-argument list. The above quote misuses "template-name" and "declarator-id", because a template-name is a plain identifier and does not contain any qualifiers. C++0x has changed the text to

> In a function template declaration, the last component of the declarator-id shall be a template-name or operator-function-id (i.e., not a template-id).

(The last part appears in cases such as `operator+()`). Even the C++0x text misses some cases - see [this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1009).

The misuse of "declarator-id" happens in the note. The note was replaced by C++0x with

> [ Note: in a class template declaration, if the class name is a ... — end note ]

In class template declarations, the name specified syntactically is a class-name instead of a declarator-id. The relation of class-name and declarator-id is as follows (very simplified...)

```
class class-name { ... } declarator-id;
class foo        { ... } bar;
```

In class template declarations, there may not be a declarator-id specified.

---

A template-id is a template-name followed by a template-argument list.

---

The quote means that in a function *template* declaration, the name must not be a template-id. In your example you declare a *function* instead of a template. There are still cases where an explicit specialization declares a template, though. But that can only happen for member function templates

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  template<typename U>
  void f();
};

// this explicit specialization *contains* a template declaration and
// declares an identifier (a template-name) qualified by A<int>:: 
template<> template<typename U> 
void A<int>::f() { }
```

Answer (score 3):

From `C++ Templates: The Complete Guide` By David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M. Josuttis

`8.3`

> **Explicit template arguments**: A template name can be followed by explicit template argument values enclosed in angle brackets. The resulting name is called a **template-id**.

For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Demo{ 
    // ... 
};

int main()
{
   Demo <int> d; // Demo is the template name, Demo<int> is the template-id
   // ...
}
```

> In a function template declaration, the declarator-id shall be a template-name (i.e., not a template-id).

For example (from what I have understood):

```
class A {
public:
    template <typename T> void f(T);
    template <typename T> struct X { };
};
class B : public A {
public:
    using A::f;     // fine
    using A::X      // fine

};
class C : public A {
public:
    using A::f<int>;     // ill formed, declarator-id shall not be a template id
    using A::X<double>   // ill formed, declarator-id shall not be a template id

};
```

Someone please correct me if I am wrong.