# Proper syntax for a templated constructor using template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to extend my (limited) understanding of class templates to class templates with template template parameters.

This declaration and constructor works fine (well, it compiles):

```
template < char PROTO >
class Test
{
public:
    Test( void );
    ~Test( void );
    void doIt( unsigned char* lhs, unsigned char* rhs );
};


template< char PROTO >
Test<PROTO>::Test( void )
{
}
```

But, when I try to do something similar using templated template parameters, I get these errors (line that sourced the errors is below):

```
error: missing ‘>’ to terminate the template argument list
error: template argument 1 is invalid
error: missing ‘>’ to terminate the template argument list
error: template argument 1 is invalid
error: expected initializer before ‘>’ token
```

```
template <char v> struct Char2Type {
enum { value = v };
};


template < template<char v> class Char2Type >
class Test2
{
public:
    Test2( void );
    ~Test2( void );
    void doIt( unsigned char* lhs, unsigned char* rhs );
};


template< template<char v> class Char2Type >
Test2< Char2Type<char v> >::Test2( void ) //ERROR ON THIS LINE
{
}
```

I'm using gnu g++.  What's wrong with the line above??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
template< template<char v> class Char2Type >
Test2<Char2Type>::Test2( void ) 
{
}
```

A template-argument for a template template-parameter shall be the **name** of a class template. 
`Char2Type` is the template-name whereas `Char2Type<char>` is the template-id. You are not allowed to use `template-id` in place of `template-name` in your example.

[Difference between template-name and template-id.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796558/difference-between-template-name-and-template-id)