# Template call: Actual specialization not called

Tags: c++, string, templates

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void test() {
   cout << "1";
}

template<>
void test<std::string>() {
   cout << "2";
}

int main() {
   test<std::string()>(); //expected output 2 but actual output 1
}
```

Why is the output 1 and not 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`test<std::string>` (note: no parentheses at the end) would yield what you expect.

Writing it as `test<std::string()>` instantiates the template with the type "function taking no arguments and returning std::string"

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to invoke the function like: `test<std::string>()`?

In your `test<std::string()>()`, the template parameter is not `std::string` but a function type (a function taking no arguments and returning `std::string`).

Answer (score 0):

`std::string()` is a [typeid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796558/difference-between-template-name-and-template-id/3797414#3797414). A typeid is a simple declaration with missing declarator id.

In a template-argument, if there is an ambiguity between a type-id and an expression the call is resolved to a type-id. So your code outputs 1

You need to remove the parentheses `()` in order to get 2 as the output i.e `foo<std::string>()` would give you output 2.