# What is the meaning of the words "last component" in §14/2?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

§14/2 (emphasis mine)

> A *template-declaration* can appear only as a namespace scope or class
>   scope declaration. In a function template declaration, the **last
>   component** of the *declarator-id* shall not be a *template-id*. [ Note:
>   That last component may be an *identifier*, an *operator-function-id*,
>   a *conversion-function-id*, or a *literal-operator-id*. In a class
>   template declaration, if the class name is a *simple-template-id*, the
>   declaration declares a class template partial specialization (14.5.5).
>   —end note ]

Note that *declarator-id* is defined in the grammar (N4140) as shown below:

*declarator-id*:
    ...<sub>*opt*</sub>   *id-expression*

*id-expression*:
    *unqualified-id*
    *qualified-id*

*unqualified-id*:
    *identifier*
    *operator-function-id*
    *conversion-function-id*
    *literal-operator-id*
    ~ *class-name*
    ~ *decltype-specifier*
    *template-id*

Given that, in a function template declaration, a *declarator-id* is an identifier, an *operator-function-id*, a *conversion-function-id*, or a *literal-operator-id*, what does it mean the expression "last component" above?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796558/difference-between-template-name-and-template-id

Comment: Last component of the *qualified-id*, if one is used.

Answer (score 2):

In your quote from the grammar, you have omitted the production for *qualified-id* which expands to a sequence of *unqualified-id*s, and **last component** refers to the last of those *unqualified-id*s.

The Standard is telling you that
a function template declaration cannot end in a *template-id*
in contrast to a partial specialisation of a class template

```cpp
template<typename T> class A {};
template<typename T> class A<std::vector<T> > {}; // ends with simple-template-id
```

even though some components of a function template's *qualified-id* could be *template-id*s, as in

```cpp
template<typename>
struct A {
    void f();
};
template<typename T>
void A<T>::f() {} // cannot end with template-id
```

Comment: Interestingly, there is a specific grammatical rule *explicit-specialization* alongside the rule *template-declaration*. So `template<> void foo<int>() {}` does use a *template-id* as the last part of the declarator, but it's not a *template-declaration*.